# What's the better approach, running multiple server-builds on one instance or running one server-build and managing matches in different rooms?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, scalability, mirror-networking

We are building a racing multiplayer game using Mirror and Unity and we've been able to successfully run the authoritative server on AWS-Gamelift and Playfab so far.
Both providers are with the flexibility of running multiple server-builds and mapping with different ports.

So I think running multiple server-build for different matches on one instance is a bit expensive in terms of server usage as compared to running one server and managing multiple matches in different rooms.
But overall it seems to be a safer option to go with since build crash and similar issues will only happen on one match and other matches (servers) will be running fine on the same machine and also it's a bit easier to handle and scale.

What's your opinion on this?
It might be useful if you share any blog or resource to look at for scaling and managing servers on gamelift/playfab.

thanks!

Comment: It sounds to me like you understand the trade-offs involved. Picking which set of pros/cons is better suited to your game is a judgement call you will need to make. There will of course be a limit to how many matches you can run in a single instance anyway, so dialing in the right scaling plan for your game will require some profiling that only you can do.

Comment: Yes exactly,
I know I will have a limited number of servers and matches on one machine in either way and I will be scaling server instances based on ccu and match requests.

Comment: So then this is really about tuning for the sweet spot between performance, reliability, and cost. Something that only someone with access to your build can do accurately.

Comment: Hmmm, thanks!
I think multiple servers mapped with different port looks fine then unless it used a lot of system resources that is unlikely to happen.